# Displaying sub groups in a group view - Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, organic-groups, drupal-panels

I've just picked up Drupal and I need to complete a task I'm not entirely sure how to do.

I need to create a hierarchy of groups :

The example groups:
Floor : 1
Floor : 2
Floor : 3

Under each floor group, I'd like to create rooms(also a group).

What I have so far :
 1. I have groups of floors.
 2. I have groups of rooms properly nested under 'floors'(using audience).
 3. I can filter and display the 'rooms' of a certain floor(but only one).

My problem :

I cannot find a way to display the rooms of a floor in each floor view.
As stated, I created a 'View' that filters out by floor, But it's not a dynamic View, That means that it doesn't accept the groupID as a parameter, it always displays the same room list, regardless of what group is viewed(as it's displayed on the website itself, and not per group).

Just to clarify, The end result should be drupal's standard installation, with the sidebar menu containing the rooms of a floor belonging to the currently viewed floor.

Using Organic groups, Organic_subgroups, Panels, views etc. as modules.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think using Organic Groups for this is needlessly complex unless you have some reason to keep the information about the floors and rooms private to only members of the floors and groups. You can do this with a simple relation bu adding a field to your rooms as to what floor they are on. Then create a view that filters by floor. You can make it dynamic by using contexts under the advanced section in Views and adding the floor as the context. then your url would be simply floor/floornumber and would automatically show your list of rooms.